# Animation in Splash Screen

Tags: android, xml, animation, splash-screen

I use [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) splash screen for my app. It works fine, but I want to use animation. How can I use animation without layouts?

This my java file:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

My xml for theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorMaterialWhite"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ico" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Style:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I want rotate ico while app loading. Thank you.

**Is it even possible?**

Comment: Why are you not using Layout?

Comment: @SyedDaniyalNasir for the performance. When I run app, style with image loaded instantly.

Comment: you can´t the splashscreen can only be a simple image in the activity theme, I would recommend using a static image in the beginning and displaying an animation while the main activity is loading if you´re doing it right the user should not notice any disruption

Comment: Let me give you a code.

Comment: You are just showing the splash screen for a few seconds and then moving on to the mainScreen, right??

Comment: What kind of style are you using, can you show me?

Comment: @SyedDaniyalNasir I've updated the question, see above

Comment: Rotate in a circle?